# USB over current condition loop

Tags: usb, kernel

Recently I updated my Linux kernel, and I am experiences some problems. My usb port no longer work, and the message:

```
[ 1588.691486] usb 1-1-port1: over-current condition
[ 1588.899451] usb 1-1-port2: over-current condition
```

Loops endlessly on `dmesg`. (Full Dmesg [Here](http://pastebin.com/FFbQYwkw))

Running `lsusb` freezes and holds up for about 10 minutes until finally outputting :

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Running `lsusb -v` eventually outputs [this](http://pastebin.com/EeBmMsRc).

On shutdown the same message endlessly loops and I eventually have to just force it off.

Nothing at all is plugged into my ports.

I have already tried inserting `ehci_hcd.ignore_OC=1` into `/etc/default/grub` with no success.

I am dual booting windows 10 as well, and the USB ports are not functioning there either.

I'm not sure if this will help, but her is `uname -a` output:

```
Linux vic-Latitude-E6430s 4.4.0-66-generic #87-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 3 15:29:05 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

If anybody has any suggestions please let me know, I've been struggling with this for a few weeks now and I am out of ideas.

Comment: I feel dumb. All the problem was is that one usb port got mutilated somehow, and was shorting to ground. I should have check better earlier. Oh well.  Sorry

Comment: you should consider making your comment into a solution (and accepting it). I had the same message and the same exact problem. Your comment led me to look at the (yellow colored) USB port on my x201 Lenovo and noticed one of the pins was turned back into the outside casing, probably causing a short. After bending that pin back (while the power was turned off) and rebooting, the error message no longer appeared.